# Use a #define number into a function in C

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor

Why this code isn't working ? (This is not the actual code, but a simplified version)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER 5
int function( int NUMBER );

int main (void)
{
    function( NUMBER );
    return 0;

}
int function( int NUMBER )
{
    printf("Hi %d\n", NUMBER);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int function( int 5 );` - what?

Comment: sorry, the %d inside the function was missing

Comment: And how does it give any sense to that statement? After all, why do you use this `#define` clause here? Are you trying to create a function that works with `5` if no value is specified?

Comment: that I want to pass NUMBER (5) as a parameter, to print it in the function.

Comment: @jotape: Which you did successfully in `main`.  However, functions do not predict their input, they take arguments as variables.  This way you can also write `function(10)`, `function(100)`, and `function(some_other_variable)`.  Functions are reusable pieces of code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#define NUMBER 5
int function( int NUMBER );
```

`#define` is a pre-processor macro, simple text replacement.  So, let's look at what you are really trying to compile:

```
int function( int 5 );
```

Which makes no sense.  This part is fine:

```
int main (void)
{
    function( NUMBER );
    return 0;    
}
```

Because you are *calling* `function` with the value `5`, but the signature of `function` should look like this:

```
int function( int x );  // the argument is a variable, x
```

Comment: So NUMBER is not a variable ?

Comment: no, NUMBER is not a variable. It's like a cut and paste operation that happens before compilation.

Comment: @jotape: As Lee said (as well as my answer), no, it is not.  However, even then it wouldn't make much sense given how you're attempting to use it.  When you write something like `void foo(int x)` `x` is a variable *local to the function* `foo`.  It does not exist outside the function.

Comment: Or rather (@Lee): it's like a **search-and-replace** operation that happens before compilation.

Comment: well, same kind of idea (search for NUMBER and paste in 5) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
 #define NUMBER 5
 int function( int NUMBER );
```

is the same as:

```
 int function( int 5 );
```

You cannot have a number for a parameter name.

Comment: So a constant is what I need?

Comment: What you need is to read a book about C Programming and learn the basics.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because what you are doing makes no sense. Read the answers above to understand why.

It should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER 5

void function ( int );  // a function prototype, saying 'function' accepts an int as the first argument.

int main ( void ) // the 'main' is called when the program runs.
{
   function ( NUMBER );
   return 0;  // returning zero means that no error was encounter in the program
}

void function( int i )
{
   printf ( "Hi %d\n", i );
}
```

Comment: You meant to write `x` where you wrote `i` in `function`, here: `printf("Hi %i\n", i)`.

Answer (score 1):

After preprocessing, your code looks like this:

```
int function( int 5 );

int main (void)
{
    function( 5 );
    return 0;

}
int function( int 5 )
{
    printf("Hi %d\n", 5 );
    return 0;
}
```

That is, all occurrences of the symbol `NUMBER` are replaced with the integer constant `5` before the code is compiled.  This works fine in the *call* to `function`, but not in the declaration or definition; a parameter *name* cannot be an integral constant expression.

You will need to change the declaration and definition so that the parameter is not named `NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

The line with `int function( int NUMBER );` is a function prototype, yes?  You should omit NUMBER in it.  Also, your function definition should have its own input variable name - don't use NUMBER, so make it like this:

```
int function( int num )
{
    printf("Hi\n");
    return 0;
}
```